# Auth Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

This error occur when I debug only in android simulator and real device.

> W/Firestore( 2910): (24.9.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(categories order by id, **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

In ios simulator, all good. There is nor orderBy filter in my database_service.

What is this error and how to fix this?

I tried firebase rule to

```
match /promotions/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /products/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /categories/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

but doesn't work.

```
Stream<List<Category>> getAllCategories() {
return _firebaseFirestore
    .collection('categories')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) {
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Category.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
});}

Stream<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
return _firebaseFirestore
    .collection('products')
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .map((snapshot) {
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Product.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
});}

Stream<List<Promotion>> getAllPromotions() {
return _firebaseFirestore
    .collection('promotions')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) {
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Promotion.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
});}
```

this is my code to get data form Firestore.

```
Future<void> checkAuthenticationStatus() async {
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
if (user == null) {
  // User is not authenticated
  print('User is not authenticated.');
 
} else {
  // User is authenticated
  print('User is authenticated: ${user.uid}');
  
}
});}
```

This is my auth check method.

Comment: Please edit your question to also include the **code** that triggers this error against your rules, and in that code **prove** that you're meeting the requirement (i.e. check that there is a signed in user).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Try change rules to `If true`, If read succeed it's authentication issue, If still failing I guess is about ios configurations.